# Symfony 3: FOSSUserBundle get a JsonResponse Instead of redirecting

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, fosuserbundle

On my Symnfony3 project I noticed that during registration some events are generated where I can override the response. eg. Instead of rendering the default twig template and redirect to just return a JsonResponse with a successMessage.

Therefore I did the following Event Subscriber:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use AppBundle\Constants\AjaxJsonResponseConstants;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;

class UserRegistrationResponseChanger implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        $subscribedEvents=[
//              FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE=>[],
                FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED=>[],
                FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS=>["setJsonResponseOnSuccess",-1],
                FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE=>["setJsonResponseOnFailure",-1],
//              FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM=>[],
//              FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED=>[]
        ];
    }

    public function setJsonResponseOnSuccess(FormEvent $formEvent)
    {
        $response=['status'=>AjaxJsonResponseConstants::AJAX_ACTION_SUCCESS,'message'=>"User Sucessfully Registered please check your mail."];
        $response=new JsonResponse($response);
        $formEvent->setResponse($response);

        return $response;
    }

    public function setJsonResponseOnFailure(FormEvent $formEvent)
    {
        $response=['status'=>AjaxJsonResponseConstants::AJAX_ACTION_FAIL,'message'=>"You cannot register please try again later"];
        $response=new JsonResponse($response);
        $formEvent->setResponse($response);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Also on my `services.yml` I have put the following:

```
 app.user_register.subscriber:
  class: AppBundle\EventSubscriber\UserRegistrationResponseChanger
  tags:
   - { name: app.user_register.subscriber }
```

And the command

In order to override on how the response will get returned but somehow it fails to do so and redirects to the default page. What I try to acheive it to perform the registration via ajax call instead of rendering the registration page and redirecting.

Comment: When the registration is successful you will get a 302 Redirect response, otherwise a BadRequest one. If you don't need to return any specific data when it is successful you can just wait for the 302 in your Ajax call and handle it the way you need since you can assume it was successful. Let me know If your registration error listener is not working so I will post an answer with a working example.

Comment: I need to return Json because I want to implement single page application and all "redirections" will be done via Javascript instead of 302 redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this steps:

First of all you should use `kernel.event_subscriber` instead of `app.user_register.subscriber` when you define the event subscriber therfore your subscriber will be defined like that:

```
 app.user_register.subscriber:
  class: AppBundle\EventSubscriber\UserRegistrationResponseChanger
  tags:
   - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

To the `services.yml`.

Furthermore the `getSubscribedEvents` must return the array of the listeners. Also the  `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED` **MUST** Have a listener even if it isdoes not have an implementation, if you do not want a listener just comment the like.

In the end your listener shuld be implemented like that:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use AppBundle\Constants\AjaxJsonResponseConstants;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;

class UserRegistrationResponseChanger implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        $subscribedEvents=[
//              FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE=>[],
//              FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED=>[],
                FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS=>["setJsonResponseOnSuccess",-1],
                FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE=>["setJsonResponseOnFailure",-1],
//              FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM=>[],
//              FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED=>[]
        ];

        return $subscribedEvents;
    }

    public function setJsonResponseOnSuccess(FormEvent $formEvent)
    {
        $response=['status'=>AjaxJsonResponseConstants::AJAX_ACTION_SUCCESS,'message'=>"User Sucessfully Registered please check your mail."];
        $response=new JsonResponse($response);
        $formEvent->setResponse($response);

        return $response;
    }

    public function setJsonResponseOnFailure(FormEvent $formEvent)
    {
        $response=['status'=>AjaxJsonResponseConstants::AJAX_ACTION_FAIL,'message'=>"You cannot register please try again later"];
        $response=new JsonResponse($response);
        $formEvent->setResponse($response);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad you make it work but I believe the actual problem is that you should prioritize the `REGISTRATION_SUCCESS`event, besides tagging as `kernel.event_subscriber` like you said. I've added an answer that may help others as well.

Comment: I didn't edit because I didn't fully agree with your answer. It didn't say about the  priorities and your statement that a `REGISTRATION_COMPLETED` event must have a listener is wrong. Also, note that you do not need to return the response.

Answer (score 1):

You should prioritize the `REGISTRATION_SUCCESS` event when you have registration confirmation (default behaviour in FOSUserBundle), see http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html#registration-success-listener-with-enabled-confirmation-at-the-same-time

The service definition needs to be like this:

```
#app/config/services.yml
app.security_registration_success:
    class: Path\To\Your\EventListener\RegistrationSuccessListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

An example of a registration success listener:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Path\To\Your\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class RegistrationSuccessListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => [['onRegistrationSuccess', -10]]];
    }

    public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event): void
    {
        $event->setResponse(new JsonResponse());
    }
}
```